# Schedule for Raspi OS upgrades to 5.5 kernel & libgpiod 1.5

Tags: gpio, kernel, libgpiod

Several months ago, [this blog post](https://microhobby.com.br/blog/2020/02/02/new-linux-kernel-5-5-new-interfaces-in-gpiolib/) appeared in a search. In summary, this post outlines the new char device-based GPIO interfaces. It further states that a *full complement* of features will be available with the release of the 5.5 Linux kernel, and `libgpiod` ver 1.5.

Since reading this announcement, I've been expecting to see a more-or-less *official schedule* from the RPi Organization announcing a date for release of these upgrades. I've probably just missed the announcement, but I've seen nothing at all on this through [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/).

I have two questions:

1. Has there been an *"official"* announcement on the expected release date?
2. Is there a reasonably safe & straightforward method for upgrading to the 5.5 kernel and libgpiod 1.5? For example: `rpi-update`??

I'd like to hear from anyone who has tried this upgrade.

Comment: I quickly googled and sadly found nothing updated or interesting. I guess I need t wait till 2022 to find anything interesting. Cheers. BTW, the most updated I read so far are: (1) An Introduction to chardev GPIO and Libgpiod on the Raspberry PI - Craig Peacock, Embedded Linux 2018oct16
https://www.beyondlogic.org/an-introduction-to-chardev-gpio-and-libgpiod-on-the-raspberry-pi/

(2) Architectures/ARM/gpio - FedoraProject - 2019
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM/gpio

(3) GPIO - LinuxSunxi
https://linux-sunxi.org/GPIO / to continue, ...

Comment: (4) Support for libgpiod as pin factory? - GPIOZero issues/840 
https://github.com/gpiozero/gpiozero/issues/840. PS - I am a python and GUI guy and rarely use CLI staff..

Comment: I'm not sure the Foundation will be that bothered.  There are a plethora of existing libraries which will always outperform libgpiod on the Pi.  I'd only expect to see interest if they are forced to move from the Broadcom SoC.

Comment: @joan: Is it true that the `sysfs` interface to GPIO [has been deprecated & will be removed from the kernel?](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/Documentation/ABI/obsolete/sysfs-gpio?id=fe95046e960b4b76e73dc1486955d93f47276134) If so, what result?

Comment: It has been deprecated.  I have no idea when it will be removed. Those GPIO libraries which depend upon sysfs will then stop working and will need to be rewritten or be abandoned.  I doubt pigpio will be updated to use libgpiod rather than syfs.  wiringPi is deprecated.  I don't know about bcm2853.  The author of the Python RPi.GPIO is making changes.

Comment: I had better clarify.  pigpio makes almost zero use of sysfs and won't need any changes when it is deprecated.  As far as I can remember the bcm2853 library is like pigpio in not needing sysfs.  WiringPi does make more use but it would still remain functional without sysfs.

Comment: Interesting... 3+ years on, and **we are still waiting on libgpiod**.